How to set up CMS Content with Search Results on an enhanced LWR Experience Cloud site?
I followed the instructions from Salesforce here but can't seem to get the 'Results Source' option to allow CMS Content. It only allows CRM Objects.
Can anyone please help me figure out what is going on?

We have a Gov Cloud org and Salesforce let me know that CMS Content search in an LWR Site is not available in Gov Cloud orgs. Hope this helps anyone else with a Gov Cloud org.
